# Hover work when i turn on devtools but dont work when i turn off devtools?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

when i hover to image when devtools not turn on, it dont working but when i open when devtools and hover again. It finally work ??
I have been trying in difference browser but the same problem is happened, everyone help me solved this.
It was happened when i used setTimeout and clearTimeout in difference function, it would be nice if you can help solved this or idea of write code in difference ways.

```
const handleHover = () => {
    //set time out here
    setHandleDelay(setTimeout(() => {
    setHover(true)
    }, 1000 ))
}
const handleNotHover = () => {
    //i want to clear time out here when it not hover
    clearTimeout(handleDelay)
    setHover(false)                    
}
return (
         <div key={movie.id} 
         onMouseOver={() => handleHover()} 
         onmouseover{() => handleNotHover()}>
         <div>...</div>
       )
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank for everyone i have already fine the solution. It is stupid of me for mistake at event onMouseOver and onMouseEnter.

It was better to use onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave when you hover on element in Reactjs

```
<div
onMouseEnter={() => handleHover()} 
onMouseLeave={() => handleNotHover()} />
```

Comment: Its great that you found the solution. But please provide more information as to what was going on and how you solved it, as you have it the answer is very unclear as to how you actually fixed the problem. Others may have the same issue as you, and will want to know how you fixed it. Please update your answer to provide those details.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).